# Removing duplicates from an Array of Strings, without explicit comparison in Java

Tags: java, comparison, duplicates

What would be the best means of going about this without explicit comparison?

Comment: I guess you'd have to use covert comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028330/remove-duplicates-from-object-array-data-java

Comment: Adding it to a HashSet and then using .toArray() to convert back to array does the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If List Of Object contains `Strings` , You need to Add them to `Set`.

If the list contains Custom object , override equals meth in the custom class and those object to `Set`

Comment: Note: primitives are the basic types like `char`, `int`, etc. `String` is not a primitive. You only have to override `equals` if you want to add custom objects.

Comment: No, implement `Comparable`, and override `compareTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `Collection` named `Set`, **which maintains Uniqueness.**

**-** Use `asList()` **method** of `Array` to convert it into `List`, and then use `addAll()` method to **add** the `List` to the `Set`.

**-** Adding `List` to the `Set` will **remove the duplicates**.

**Eg:**

```
String[] arr = {"Vivek","John","Rick"};

ArrayList<String> arList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));

TreeSet<String> arSet = new TreeSet<String>();

arSet.addAll(arList);       // duplicates removed
```